# Raise exception from SQL-only stored function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I've successfully created a UDT called `monetary` which is a composite type of two values, an integer currency ID and numeric amount. The special thing about monetary values is that they are the same as numeric, except that you can't add two values from different currencies together. I've created a number of operators (`CREATE OPERATOR`) to perform operations such as add and subtract, and this is all working really well.

These operators `RAISE EXCEPTION` if the currency component of the two operands is not the same. For this reason I've had to write the functions in plpgsql. But I would prefer to write these functions in SQL because I understand that the function bodies would then be inlined in queries.

I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
create function monetary_add(a monetary, b monetary) returns monetary language sql immutable as $$
  select (a).value + (b).value where exception_if((a).currency <> (b).currency);
$$;
```

but I can't find an SQL function which could raise an exception.

I could write one in plpgsql, of course, but that would defeat the purpose. Is there a built in function to do this? And am I correct that writing the functions in SQL result in faster execution of queries?

Comment: IIRC, you have to write your own function to do that.

Comment: Exceptions are **not** part of SQL. The best you could do in this  case is to return NULL when the currency types do not match. Typically an SQL will be faster, not guaranteed.

Comment: Error conditions certainly are part of SQL. Just try dividing by zero! But the question is about Postgresql, which certainly does have exceptions. I was simply hoping there might be an SQL function which triggered an exception.